# Temperature Converter is giving me NaN

Tags: javascript, converters

I need to make a temperature converter using forms and it has to have the ok button display the information and a clear button to clear all information.

This is what I have tried to do but it gives me NaN

```js
function temperatureConverter(valNum) {
    
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
    
  document.getElementById("outputCelcius").innerHTML=(valNum-32)/1.8;
    
}
```

```html
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>

Ok now my issue is that I need everything cleared even the Celsius data but I can't find a way for it to work        
<p>Type a value in the Fahrenheit field to convert te value to Celsius:</p>
    
<p>
    
  <label>Fahrenheit</label>

  <input id="inputFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit">

  <input id= "button1" type= "button" value= "OK"  onclick="temperatureConverter(this.value)">

  <input id= "reset1" type= "reset" value= "Clear" onclick="temperatureConverter">
    
</p>
    
<p>Celcius: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>
```

Comment: Well what values are you passing into `temperatureConverter()`?  Typically `NaN` would mean that you are passing in non numeric inputs.

Comment: I was putting in -40 and 32

Comment: Then it should be working.  Please edit your question and give an exact reproducible example for when the problem happens.

Comment: You are passing the value of the button element, not the value of the text field. try replacing `this.value` with `document.querySelector('#inputFahrenheit').value`

Comment: In the button, `this.value` is the string `OK`.

Comment: What do you expect `onclick="temperatureConverter"` in the reset button to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because in your `#button1` you wrote:

```
onclick="temperatureConverter(this.value)"
```

where `this` is not `#inputFahrenheit` but `#button1`. Therefore `this.value` actually equals to `"OK"`.

To fix your problem, you need to change your `temperatureConverter` function to get value of `#inputFahrenheit` instead of using `onclick="temperatureConverter(this.value)"`.

Similar situation happens in your `#reset1`, therefore your reset input will not work as well. You need to apply the same concept into your reset function, which I suggest to create a new function dedicated just for that.

Generally, it is not encouraged to use the same function to perform completely different actions.

```js
function temperatureConverter(){
  var input = document.getElementById('inputFahrenheit');
  var value = input.value;
  value = parseFloat(value);
  
  var output = document.getElementById('outputCelcius');
  output.innerHTML = (value - 32)/1.8;
}

function resetTemperature(){

  /* clear the temperature */
  console.log('clear');

}
```

```html
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
    
<p>Type a value in the Fahrenheit field to convert te value to Celsius:</p>
    
<p>
    
  <label>Fahrenheit</label>

  <input id="inputFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit">

  <input id= "button1" type= "button" value= "OK"  onclick="temperatureConverter()">

  <input id= "reset1" type= "reset" value= "Clear" onclick="resetTemperature()">

</p>
    
<p>Celcius: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics needed to get your code working. Basically it is simply just changing what value is passed to the `temperatureConverter` function. Before you were passing it the value of the button that was being clicked, not the value of the input element you were trying to read. Also, I'm unsure on this one as I didn't look it up, but the reset element wasn't working for me until I put your items inside of a `<form>` element.

```js
function temperatureConverter(valNum) {
    
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
    
  document.getElementById("outputCelcius").innerHTML=(valNum-32)/1.8;
    
}
```

```html
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
    
<p>Type a value in the Fahrenheit field to convert te value to Celsius:</p>
<form>    
<p>
    
  <label>Fahrenheit</label>

  <input id="inputFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit">

  <input id= "button1" type= "button" value= "OK"  onclick="temperatureConverter(document.querySelector('#inputFahrenheit').value)">

  <input id= "reset1" type= "reset" value= "Clear">
    
</p>
</form>
    
<p>Celcius: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>
```

Please note that most of the time, people don't like putting the event listener in the `on[event]` attributes, and many developers will prefer that you do something more like this:

```js
// () => {} is something called Arrow function notation, if you didn't know it already.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  function updateOutput(value) {
    // make sure you do some checking to avoid XSS attacks.
    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = value;
  }
  // keeps the form from submitting since we don't have an actual form handler and this is all front-end
  document.querySelector('#converterForm').addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  document.querySelector('#convert').addEventListener('click', () => {
    updateOutput(convertToCelsius(document.querySelector('#fahrenheit').value));
  });
});

function convertToCelsius(f) {
  if(typeof f == 'string') f = parseFloat(f, 10);
  if(isNaN(f)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid parameter passed to function convertToCelsius');
  }
  return (f-32) * 5 / 9; 
}
```

```html
<form id="converterForm" action="/">
  <input type="number" id="fahrenheit" placeholder="Fahrenheit value">
  <input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert to Celsius">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</form>
```

Other than that, a good way to check why a function isn't working is to use `console.log` in your code and then check the Javascript browser (in Chrome you can get to it by hitting `ctrl+shift+j`, in Firefox I believe it's `ctrl+shift+i`).

Answer (score 0):

can't see you using any form.

your function,

```
function temperatureConverter(valNum) {        
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);

  document.getElementById("outputCelcius").innerHTML=(valNum-32)/1.8;

}
```

then,

```
<form id="tempConverter">
  Convert: <input type="text" id="unit" name="converter" />
  <input
   type="button"
   value="Submit" 
   onclick="temperatureConverter(document.getElementById('unit').value);"
  />
 </form>

<p>Celcius: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>
```

apparently, if you console the value, you were obviously sending "OK" as param to the function(not the value of input field) which is NAN.